# Silverlight 5, ria services with entity framework 6.0 alpha 3

Tags: silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a silverlight 5.0 application using ria services, with entityframework 6.0 alpha 3. This is a greenfield project that never used any other version of entityframework. Everything seems to compile fine, except for the silverlight data project that connects to the web project to generate proxies. I get the following error:

Error   2   Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'

Is there an incompatibility or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIA Services [is now OpenSource](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2013/07/03/ria-services-is-getting-open-sourced.aspx) with the name "Open RIA Services" (see [on CodePlex](https://openriaservices.codeplex.com/)).

Colin Blair, the project leader, has just announced the first version with EF6 support :
http://www.openriaservices.net/blog/post/The-Open-RIA-Services-Blog/1016/4-3-Alpha-NuGet-Packages-Released/

You can install the Nuget package : [RIA Services for Entity Framework 6+](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RIAServicesContrib.EntityFramework).

<del>If you want to install the Nuget package [RIA Services for Entity Framework 6+](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RIAServicesContrib.EntityFramework), be sure to select the "include prerelease" item in the top combo Box.</del>

Answer (score 1):

The latest supported version for WCF RIA Services is [Entity Framework 5](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2012/12/10/RIA-Services-NuGet-Package-Updates-ndash-Including-Support-for-EntityFramework.aspx). So i would not expect that this will work with EF 6.0.